# Bug in votes count on user profile

Tags: support, voting, vote-count

On [my user page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/199958/hobbit-hole), there is the votes count on the "Summary" page, which shows my correct number of votes.

[image: shows all my up and down votes]

However, if I go to my [Votes tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/199958/hobbit-hole?tab=votes) and select "Downvotes," it says I have casted 0 downvotes.

[image: 0 downvotes]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: probably some caching or lazy refreshing

Comment: @HugoDozois Refreshing and/or clearing cache does nothing. Also, I've been downvoting for around a month now IIRC, so if it caches that long, something is wrong.

Comment: The answer, and it pains me to say it, is "get more rep".

Comment: @JarrodDixon Just wondering, why did you remove the "bug" tag from this? Anna said the people here were going to look into it. Also, I don't think it's a duplicate of said question.

Comment: @HugoDozois Anna couldn't see that one of your downvotes was actually undone (deleted) by you, which means it doesn't count.  The three other, *active* downvotes are on deleted posts, which you can't see now, but we still include in your total number of votes.  That's what the linked duplicate explains.

Comment: @HobbitHole Jarrod is the one who looked into this. I was wrong on a couple counts, apparently. My bad.

Comment: @Jarrod in such case the text is misleading, why not something like "You have no votes on non deleted posts"?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd that is too good of an idea, sorry.  LET CONFUSION REIGN! (I'll look into it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have cast 4 downvotes, 3 of them on deleted posts. I'm tentatively inclined to blame caching of some form on this one - I see all four on your Votes tab right now, and when it updates for you,  you should be able to see the one vote that wasn't cast on a now-deleted post.

Although you're right - it's odd that it hasn't updated yet for you. The votes are old. Are you sure you are signed in?

(Disclaimer: I work for SE. Normal moderators can't view the detailed breakdown of other people's upvotes/downvotes.)

Comment: Still hasn't updated for me. I am logged in.

Comment: @HobbitHole Yeah, that's not right. We're gonna look into it.

Comment: I'll be pushing out a better votes view for you, @AnnaLear - you're unable to see that one of the votes is deleted and doesn't count.

Comment: @AnnaLear stumbled on this thread as I was about to post a question like "SE down vote count in error ?"  I got a critic badge, but my down vote is zero. ( Not sure if I ever did down vote over on SE, but I must have to have gotten that badge ?? ) If the down voted post was deleted, then the count could be off ?   In anycase, this seems like an " off by X " error --- 1 in my case.  This probably doesn't rise to the level of a question ... so here it is :)

Comment: @HowardPautz The post wasn't deleted, but it looks like you retracted the downvote after casting it. The badge was awarded because you did cast it and we don't retract badges once they're awarded. So, in short, status-bydesign. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear  ahhh, the other most common mistake: "User Error" :-O